# ASP .NET Core 1.1 web api using Secret Manager tool

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I a trying to set up google sign in in my .net core web api application. I have been following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins

But for some reason i get this error:

> 'IConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddUserSecrets' and no extension method 'AddUserSecrets' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'IConfigurationBuilder' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here's my startup method, nothing special here:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
        builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
    }

    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the relevant package to use it. The package is called `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets`, you can learn more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets).

Comment: Huh, i dont know how i missed that. Thanks!